# What do I have to import for SpringMVC3.2 unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, import

I am writing SpringMVC3.2 unit test and I imported classes:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

this.mockMvc.perform(post("/maps.do").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .param("mobileno", "111111")
                .param("fromdate", "22-02-2013").param("fromtime", "07:37")
                .param("todate", "22-02-2013").param("totime", "08:17")
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().mimeType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"));
```

But print() and mimeType() still are not resolved. I have been searching but I could not find correct answer.

Thanks.

EDITED
I tried to

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.server.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
```

but it could not be resolved. What library am I missing and dependency do I add?
Above is misspell and below is correct.

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
```

Comment: Have you find something?

Answer (score 10):

```
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers
```

Comes from spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar in my workspace